# What is the meaning of (something which sounds like) "nö", "ne" or "no" at the end of a sentence?

Tags: single-word-request, slang, interjection

I commonly hear people saying something like:

> - Aber du wirst mir noch den Rest heute bezahlen,  *ne*?
> - Heute fühle ich mich nicht wohl, *ne*!

oder

> - Versuch es anders, *ne!*

I've tried to capture in the previous sentences the most diverse significantly different situations in which I've heard it.

I assume that it means *oder?* but:

1. Which is the right spelling? If it's not standard, which is the pronuntiation?
2. Which are all the possible meanings? (I assume they are not a lot)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct spelling is *[ne](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne#Interjection_2)* and it's a common but informal interjection in many parts of Germany. It replaces *nicht wahr?* and *oder?* in some dialects. Note, that it does not mean *Nein* in this context<sup>1</sup>.

The pronunciation may vary between dialects from a clear German e-sound to a German ä-sound. But it's definitely not pronounce with an ö-sound. *Nö* would again be *Nein*<sup>1</sup>:

> Siehst du doch auch so, ne?
>
> Nö, seh' ich nicht so.

The German a-sound may be used as well but I guess it's rather used when you're challenging someone.

> Naaaa? Schaffst du es oder brauchste Hilfe?

Typically, the *ne*-interjection is used likewise to *isn't it?* in English. Thus, your second and third example is somewhat weird as being exclamations which are usually not followed by *ne*.

Apart, in my dialect you may hear *wa* instead of *ne*.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Ne* (or *nö*) can also mean *Nein* but than it's preceding the sentence and not following it.

Comment: The `e` in `ne` can also be pronounces as a schwa, which might be mistaken for an `ö`.

Comment: This is also subject to regional preferences. In Schwaben, you can tack on a "gelle?" to almost any sentence. In the Western Rhine area near Aachen, it will be "Wa?". I've seen bumper stickers with "Aachen, wa?" !

Comment: Und in Sachsen ist es `nu`, nu? Und gelegentlich hört man auch ein ungefärbtes nicht, nicht?